# How to deform mesh based on vertex groups or any control points

Tags: mesh, vertex-groups

I want to deform a mesh to be similar to another mesh. I need to use control points for both meshes as the shape of the target mesh is smaller than the original mesh.

an example is if I have a full arm complete with the hand, and I have another mesh that is only the hand part and no arm, is there a way to use the vertex groups to deform the first mesh to be similar to the second mesh in shape? or are there any alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: What happens to the arm in your example? It's unclear how you want to deform the mesh. Shrinkwrap modifier could be an option.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the arm should be unchanged. I want each finger individual finger from the source mesh to be similar in shape to the target mesh without deforming the arm part. 
Yeah I tried was using shrinkwrap with vertice groups on the source target, but I can't do vertice group to vertice group, only vertice group to mesh.

Sorry, I'm a bit new to blender as well